# Android: some problems using dynamic layout with ImageView

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, imageview

I am developing an Android Game and I need a dynamic layout for my Bestiary, which displays a '???' image (R.drawable.ignoto) if a certain monster has not been discovered and an image with its name otherwise. The code is the following:

```
package fogames.tamagomonsters;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;


public class BestiaryMenuActivity extends Activity {

    int[] monstersId = new int[]{R.drawable.ignoto, R.drawable.m001, R.drawable.m002, R.drawable.m003};
    int backgroundId;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
        ImageView background = new ImageView(this);
        background.setBackgroundResource(backgroundId);
        fl.addView(background);

        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(this);
        fl.addView(sv);

        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        sv.addView(ll);

        ImageView m001 = new ImageView(this);
        ImageView m002 = new ImageView(this);
        ImageView m003 = new ImageView(this);


        if (Settings.mgot[0])
            m001.setBackgroundResource(monstersId[1]);
        else
           m001.setBackgroundResource(monstersId[0]);

        if (Settings.mgot[1])
            m002.setBackgroundResource(monstersId[2]);
        else
            m002.setBackgroundResource(monstersId[0]);

        if (Settings.mgot[2])
            m003.setBackgroundResource(monstersId[3]);
        else
            m003.setBackgroundResource(monstersId[0]);


        ll.addView(m001);
        ll.addView(m002);
        ll.addView(m003);


        this.setContentView(fl);
    }
}
```

I have got two issues with this code:

1. When I access the Bestiary menu, only the last ImageView appears.
2. Is there any way I can use an array to handle these ImageViews so to avoid a mess when 100+ monsters be included?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand: do you need to create dynamically hundreds ImageViews on the layout? However why in your code you're adding ImageViews in a LinearLayout but I can see just ones (m001) with a setBackground

Comment: Yes– or something equivalent

Comment: Probably you need to use an adaptor linked to a ListView... Did you try?

Comment: You are right, its a mistake.

Comment: I don't know much about custom adapters...

Comment: It's more simple than you think... Have a look the link I wrote in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case using ListView and Adapter is the best solution.

Have look at [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) very clear example